# Is this condition on continuity extraneous or troublesome?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

I was trying to motivate the use of open sets for defining continuity (as in topology or metric spaces).

I came to formulate the following definition of continuity for a function $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Let $f(x) = y$, for $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$

Then $f$ is continuous at $x$, if for all set $M \subset Y$, $y \in M$, there exists a set $N \subset X$, $x \in N$ such that $\textbf{f(N) = M}$.

NOTE: The sets $N$ and $M$ are assumed to be connected.

Will this definition of continuity work (as you can see, it doesn't involve open sets)?

Are there any trivial counterexamples?

Comment: The function $f$ is not necessarily surjective, so, in general, you won't have $f(N) = M$. Also, you need open sets.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to make of all this, but note that it's always true that $N \subset N' \implies f(N) \subset f(N')$. It seems to me that your second condition is a tautology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definition of $f: X \rightarrow Y$ being continuous is that if $M \subseteq Y$ is *open* in $Y$, then $f^{-1}M$ is open in $X$.  If you want to talk about continuity, you need to somehow be talking about open sets.  You can't just talk about any old subsets.

Another standard definition is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if for any open set $M$ of $Y$ containing the point $f(x)$, there exists an open set $N$ of $X$ containing the point $x$, such that $f(N) \subseteq M$.  (in the case $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, this is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of what it means for a function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be continuous at a point.  do you see why?)

> Fact (try to prove this using the definitions): $f$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is continuous at every $x \in X$.

Some comments on your definition:

-Your first statement (1) is true if and only if $f$ is surjective.  It has nothing to do with $f$ being continuous.  To see what I'm getting at, take the function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ (let's forget about continuity for a second).  This function isn't surjective.  Let $x = 1/2$, so $y = f(x) = 1/4$.  Let $M$ be the set $(-1, 1)$.  Then $y \in M$, but there doesn't exist any set $N$ containing $1/2$ (in fact, there doesn't exist any subset $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ whatsoever) with the property that $f(N) = M$, because the negative numbers in $M$ are not mapped to by anything in $\mathbb{R}$ under the function $f$.

-Suppose we change your first statement (1) to the definition I gave for $f$ being continuous at $x$.  Then your second statement (2) is false.

Comment: To see why (2) is false assuming the change I suggested in (1), let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function $f(x) = x$.  Let $x = 0$ so also $y = 0$.  Let $M = (-3,3)$ and $M' = (-4,4)$.  The set $N = (-2,2)$ works as you said it does for $M$ (by which I mean $f(N) \subseteq M$), and the set $N' = (-1,1)$ works for $M'$.  But while $M \subseteq M'$, we have $N \not\subset N'$.

Comment: Let's say we impose the restriction that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective. Now, where does condition (1) lack? I am basically trying to see why I need open sets in my definition.

Comment: Because every surjective function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ satisfies property (1).  If $x$ is any point of $X$, and $M$ is any subset of $Y$ containing the point $y = f(x)$, let $N$ be the set $f^{-1}(M)$.  Then $N$ is a subset of $X$ containing the point $x$, and $f(N) = M$.

Comment: (it is true for any surjective function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ that $f(f^{-1}(M)) = M$, for every subset $M \subseteq Y$.)

Comment: Please check the latest edit I made to the post. Now I am having trouble seeing why my definition would fail for continuous functions. To illustrate, my definition would give, for $R^1$, the usual delta-epsilon definition, with the modification that instead of $(f(x)- \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon)$ and $(x- \delta, x + \delta)$, you would get $[f(x)- \epsilon, f(x) + \epsilon]$ and $[x- \delta, x + \delta]$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample to the following claim: Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces with $x \in X$, and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ a function with the following property: if $M \subseteq Y$ is a connected set containing $y$, then there exists a connected set $N \subseteq X$ containing $x$, such that $M = f(N)$.  Then $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Let $X$ be the unit interval $[0,1]$ (in the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$) and let $Y = \{0, 1\}$ with the discrete topology (all subsets are open).  Then the only connected subsets of $Y$ are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$.  Define $f:[0,1] \rightarrow Y$ by $f(0) = 0$, and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in (0,1]$.  Then $f$ is not continuous at $0$, but it satisfies the property above for $x = 0$.  Also $y = 0$, and the only connected set $M$ containing $y$ is $\{0\}$.  And $N = \{0\}$ is a connected subset of $[0,1]$ containing $x$ with the property that $f(N) = M$.  So your definition is satisfied by things which aren't continuous.